# Add new divs until count to 9 or 6 or 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be there is 9 divs with class foo or 6 or 3
It just have to be those three numbers
example:
If the elements on the page with class foo are 4
Add new div tags with class foo until they count to 6
If they 2 count to 3, If they 7 count to 9

This is my code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/H6bky/

This the html

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
</div>
```

and this the css code

```
#content{
width: 510px;  
background: #ccc;
height: 800px;
}

.foo{
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
background: #808080;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: So...Use Modulus, create a loop and append the elements....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H6bky/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
onePostlength = $(".foo").length;
if (onePostlength < 9 && onePostlength % 3 !=0)
{
    while ($(".foo").length % 3 != 0)
    {
      $("#content").append('<div class="foo" />');  
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator

```
var current = $("div.foo").length;
while((current % 3) != 0) {     // 3 can be any other number
    $("#content").append("<div class='foo'>foo</div>");
    current++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 3 - (document.querySelectorAll('.foo').length % 3),
content = document.getElementById('content'),
div, i;

for (i=0; n<3 && i<n; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'foo';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('foo'));

    content.appendChild(div);
}
```

Find the length of `.foo` elements, if there are not a multiple of three, insert that many more divs.